# How to add or remove class to each if element changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, addclass

I have a form with jquery-validate and jquery-steps. I need to check, if one of fields is not empty, the other in a same row must be filled. As you know elements with class `"required"` must be filled. I leave every element without class required. Before going next step, it must check if there any not empty element. If there is at least one, it must add class "required" to all inputs in same row. For example if input `"name"` is filled, input `"surname"` and input `"email"` must be filled too.

```
<table bolder=1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="documentCheck" type="text">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="documentCheck" type="text">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="documentCheck" type="text">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Here what i have done before i understand that im dummy: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvRdz/16/)

```
 $(function () {
     $(".documentCheck").change(function () {
         name = $(".documentCheck").val();
         if (name.length > 0) {
             $("td").find('.req').first().addClass("required");
         }
     });
 });
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".documentCheck").on('change',"td > input",function() {
             $(this).parent().siblings().children('input').addClass('required');
         });
     });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/pvRdz/24/)

**UPDATED [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/pvRdz/30/)**

Comment: small bug. it gives required class even if we just click on it. could we fix it?

Comment: @BarsDS i gave `blur` so that it'll be easier for me to test :)
thought you'll use `change`, which you're already using in your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function () {
 $(".documentCheck").blur(function () {
     name = $(".documentCheck").val();
     if (name.length > 0) {
         $(this).parents("tr").find("input").addClass("required");
     }
     else
    {
     $(this).parents("tr").find("input").removeClass("required");
     }
 });
 });
```

Change will fire only if the previous value of the input changed. If you put the input as blank, it wont fire.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvRdz/32/)

Comment: thanks. it looks working but not as i want. if first line is empty, the others are not working